# Member roles in v13?

Tags: javascript, string, discord.js

I had a userinfo command in v12, but i made a fully new bot in v13 and i don't know if i can use the same code again. I tried using this:

```js
let mem = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member

const filteredRoles = mem.roles.cache.filter(role => role.id != message.guild.id)
const listedRoles = filteredRoles.sort((a, b) => b.position - a.position).map(role => role.toString())

//...code...

.addField('Roles:', listedRoles)
```

Error:

```
C:\Users\-----\-----\-----\node_modules\discord.js\src\util\Util.js:413
    if (typeof data !== 'string') throw new error(errorMessage);
                                        ^

RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty strings.
```

Comment: Try console logging `listedRoles`. What does it output?

Answer (score 1):

The [`MessageEmbed.addField()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageEmbed?scrollTo=addField) method accepts a **string** as its second parameter (the field's value). Your `listedRoles` is an array, you can use [`Array.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to convert it into a string.

```js
.addField("Roles: ", listedRoles.join(","))
```

---

Example working code:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {

    if (message.author.id == client.user.id) return;

    if (message.content.startsWith("!roles")) {
        const member = message.mentions.members.first() || message.member;
    
        const filteredRoles = member.roles.cache.filter(role => role.id != message.guild.id);
        const listedRoles = filteredRoles.sort((a, b) => b.position - a.position).map(role => role.toString());
    
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle(member.user.username)
            .addField("Roles", listedRoles.join(","));
    
        message.channel.send({embeds: [embed]});
    }

});
```

[image]

<sub>Tested using discord.js `^13.1.0`.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the fact that you even tested it! I hope you will have/had a good day :)

Comment: Glad I helped, consider marking my answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark, if it solved the problem you presented in your question. Happy coding. ;)